# AFNetworking - nothing works after timeout

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I'm using `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.2'` and I'm having one issue with it: once a request timeouts, all other requests would time out as well. Restart the app and requests pass fine again.

All requests go over SSL, here's my `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` init code

```
self.manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kRESTAPIBaseURLString]];
[self.manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
// TODO: invalid SSL cert
self.manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
self.manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so issue related to using AFNetworking version 2.2 on iOS 8. 
I've updated to `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.4'` and now everything works fine.